# Ajax internal page load

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

How can I load a new page in my particular div using ajax in CodeIgniter framework?

I have written the function and it works with plain php.

Example:

```
href="abc1.php" onclick="makerequest('abc1.php','div_name');return false;"> Page 1

href="abc2.php" onclick="makerequest('abc2.php','div_name');return false;"> Page 2
```

Note: ajax `makerequest` function is working properly.

My problem is: how can I pass my view file in replace of *abc1.php/abc2.php* in CodeIgniter framework? Those files are located on my *base_url/view/*. I try to retrieve the filename using controller but it isn't working.

see my code below:

```
..........................link.............
 href="<?=base_url()?>main_controller/newPage1.html" onclick="makerequest('<?=base_url()?>main_controller/newPage1.html','upper_middle');return false;">abc1 

href="<?=base_url()?>main_controller/newPage2.html" onclick="makerequest('<?=base_url()?>main_controller/newPage2.html','upper_middle');return false;">abc2 
.................................
...........controller code...

function newPage1()
{
  return $this->load->view('abc1.php');    
}
```

How can I do that? Or is there any other way to do it easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [codeignator with JQuery](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/jQuery/). Using JQuery, you load a url into an element, which could be a div as follows $('#element_id').load(url).

Note that you can replace #element_id with any valid css selector, or even use XPath.